# What does cycle mean in fatigue strength diagram?

Tags: structural-engineering, materials, stresses, strength, fatigue

[image]

A shaft at an usual factory might rotate 2000-3000 (10^3-10^4) per day. So, its rotation cycle easily reaches numbers indicated on X axis below. What does number of cycles in the diagram below exactly mean?

Is it total cycle since material is manufactured,

or

is it number of cycles representative of continuous rotation within a specific time zone, and after that use and material rests, it is set as zero (0) again?

Answer (score 1):

A cycle in terms of fatigue strength is going from no load to full load back to no load.

The frequency that the load is applied and removed is measured and there have been some well-documented failures and many reports and work into understanding the phenomenon.

See [enter link description here](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/AD0660529.pdf)
for one of many (thousands) of relevant documents.

Note a shaft could easily rotate at 2000 or 3000 rpm ie revolutions per minute, which means 960000 revolutions in 8 hours, just 2000 a day is low.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean daily but per minute, you are right. In conclusion, this cycle represents a specific time amount in which shaft rotates. When shaft stops and rests, cycle is 0 again. Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The cycles in the diagram are cycles since the structure was manufactured. It is not reset to zero automatically! A typical shaft will reach high numbers pretty quick.

In some situations, you can reset the counter by doing detailed inspections.